# Regex to test criteria for class name

Tags: ruby, regex

I am building a regex to check if a string meets the criteria for the name of a ruby class, in other words, it must be camelcase. The first character must be a capitalized letter, and all subsequent characters can be either lowercase letters or numbers. This can repeat, e.g. SomeRandomClass.

Below, I use a character class to match a single letter. Then another character class to match any letter or number one or more times.

```
'This' =~ /^([A-Z][a-z0-9]+)$/
 # => 0
```

But Ruby classes can have just a capital letter without any subsequent lowercase letters or numbers, and so I try to make the second character class optional with `?:`, but it does not seem to be working:

```
'ThisIsATest' =~ /^([A-Z](?:[a-z0-9]+))+$/
 # => nil
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `?:` does not make anything optional. It prevents the parenthesized part from being captured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want the following.

```
r = /
    \A           # match the beginning of the string
    [A-Z]        # match an upper case English letter
    \p{Alnum}*   # match zero or more Unicode letters or digits
    \z           # match the end of the string
    /x           # free-spacing regex definition mode

'ThisIsATest'.match? r  #=> true
'TIsAT22Test'.match? r  #=> true
'thisIsATest'.match? r  #=> false
'ThisIsATest?'.match? r #=> false
'T'.match? r            #=> true
'LeMêmeTest'.match? r   #=> true
'Être'.match? r         #=> false
''.match? r             #=> false
```

One can only test the first character (which must be a letter) for case, as any combination of upper and lower case for remaining letters can be interpreted as corresponding to a camel-case name. For example, `'TIsAT22Test'.match? r #=> true` as it could be viewed as `'T Is A T22 Test'`. Similarly `'TIsAT22test'.match? r #=> true` because it could be regarded as `'T Is A T22test'`.

It is curious that, while names of constants may contain Unicode letters, they must begin with one of the 26 English letters `A-Z`. That's through Ruby MRI 2.5.x anyway. However, one of the changes coming in Ruby MRI v2.6 (to be released December 25, 2018) is that constants can begin with some 1,853 additional characters ([source](https://medium.com/square-corner-blog/new-class-naming-rules-in-ruby-bb3b45150c37)). Presumably (I will investigate and edit to show my findings), any character `s` that satisfies `s.match? /\p{Upper}/ #=> true` can begin the name of a constant, and hence, the name of a module. If so, the regular expression above should be changed accordingly.

<sup>1. In Ruby v2.5.1 it can be seen that `Même` is a valid name for a constant: `Même = 4; Même = 5 #=> warning: already initialized constant`. However, `Être` is not. In fact, `Être` is the name of a local variable: `Être = 7; binding.local_variable_get(:Être) #=> 7`.</sup>

Comment: This one fails though with something like this: SomePracticeTest22. That is a valid class name.

Comment: I changed it to this: /\A(?:\p{Upper}[a-z0-9]*)+\z/x

Comment: Good point. Thinking about it, the regex can be simplified. See my edit.